# Como copiar para área de transferência em C# Console Application

Tags: c#, console-application

Estou com dúvidas de como inserir dados para área de transferência em um projeto Console Application em c#, target structure framework .NET 5.0.

Nas pesquisas que fiz, em aplicações WPF e Form eu posso usar o `Clipboard.SetText("Texto");`, mas em aplicações console não foi possível usar com o target structure framework .NET 5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText("Texto");**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
   class Program
      {
          [STAThread]
          private static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                   Console.WriteLine("Escreva qualquer coisa, será copiada para a área de transferência");

                    var something = Console.ReadLine();

                    Clipboard.SetText(something);

                    Console.Read();
                 }
       }
}
```

Comment: Funcionou, mas tive que mudar o target structure para ".NET Framework 4.7.2", para conseguir usar a "using System.Windows.Forms;".
Muito obrigado pela ajuda.